# Zero in increment array started at 1

Tags: php

This is my code, it's for have an array :

```
$zi = '1';
for ($zi = 1; $zi <= $v['Store']['stock']; $zi++) {
              $options_array[$zi]= $zi;
}




    var_dump($options_array);
    Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

why i have the zero in my result ? 
i put $zi at 1, so why ?

Comment: Does $options_array already have anything in it prior to this? `$options_array = [];` at the beginning of this code block should make sure it is empty when you start.

Comment: I get 'array(5) { [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(5) }' when I run the loop from 1 to 5.

Comment: why are you setting $zi twice, first you are setting it to a string 1 then a numerical 1, you only need the one in the for loop constructor.

Comment: Put `$options_array = array()` at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment turned out to be correct: The issue is that you already have a property `0` in the `$options_array` before you even get to the presented code block. You can start with a fresh array using `$options_array = []` or `$options_array = array()` (for older php versions). You can also just remove property `0` with `unset($options_array[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

In php there are two kinds of arrays, numerically indexed arrays, and associative arrays. Your output seems a little suspect but I can tell you that if all the keys of a PHP array are numeric then the array will be zero based.

I see how you have $zi = '1' above, which is along the lines of what you would have to do to create a one based array, but it would be associative, and you won't be able to simply use the ++ operator. I believe even if you use a string that is a number PHP will still convert to a numerically indexed array. I recommend against trying to implement a one based array, it's insanity.

Hope this page helps https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

You start setting `$options_array` at index 1, so index 0 is whatever the default value of the underlying type is. In this case, it's an integer, so the default is 0.